# Value of map retrieval

Tags: go

When you print the result of a function with 2 return values, you will get

```
valA valB
```

Retrieving from a map can return either 1 value or two values:

```
v := m["Answer"]
v, ok := m["Answer"]
```

However, when you print `m["Answer"]`, you will always only print `v`. What exactly is the "function signature" of a map retrieval? Or is this just a special case? Here is an example showing the distinction:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    m := make(map[string]int)
    m["Answer"] = 42

    v, ok := m["Answer"]
    fmt.Println("The value:", v, "Present:", ok)

    fmt.Println(banana())
    fmt.Println(m["Answer"])
}

func banana() (int, int) {
    return 1, 2
}
```

Comment: It's a special assignment case of when there are two variables on the LHS and the map index on the RHS. You cannot get the map index index operator to return two values any other way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Special case. The same applies to other operations, among others:

read from `chan`:

```
v, ok := <- somechannel
```

casting, e.g.:

```
casted, ok := somevar.(sometype)
```

Comment: Also, range loops `for i := range x` and `for i, v := range x`